# ASP.NET validation, radio button and textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, parsing, user-input

Is there a way to change the state of the radio button depending on the value entered by the user in one of the text boxes. I’ve tried this:

```
    protected void Btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
          int TextBoxValue = int.Parse(TextBox.Text);
          
          if(TextBoxValue < 18) {
              RadioButton.Enabled = false;
          } else {
              RadioButton.Enabled = true; 
          }
    }
```

but when I click a button nothing happens.

Comment: Are you wanting to toggle the checked state of the radio button? In that case use RadioButton.Checked = true/false.

Comment: I just want to disable the whole Radio Button list if the value of specific textbox is less than 18, otherwise, the radio button list will be enable.